# What are some good modern Brisker/Chakira based analysis sefarim by masechta?

Tags: talmud-gemara, jewish-books, brisk

I'm a big fan of the Brisker/Chakira approach to gemara b'iyun and looking for a sefer that I can use to learn either alone or with a chavrusa.

I'm looking for something in Hebrew, and (a) by masechta, and (b) something more modern than the Briskers themselves.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) MJG and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Have you read any works by R Aharon Lichtenstein

Comment: @DoubleAA I have, they're good, but I found them a little longwinded and quite hard to follow. Also not so classically 'brisk' in the straight chakira sense. But I haven't seen all the volumes.

Comment: If you found them hard to follow I don't know how you can understand R Chaim. Long-winded is more like explicit, unlike most classic briskers who are obfuscatingly terse. I also don't know what you mean by the striaght chakira sense. Unless indeed you are looking for a more simplified presentation of sugyot.

Comment: MJG why so many rollbacks? People with a lot of experience are trying to help

Comment: Rav Avraham Eliyahu Kaplan (1890-1924) wanted to write a thorough peirush of the entire Shas based on the Brisker-chakira style limud, but unfortunately he was niftar young before he was able to write much more than an (long) introduction. Rav Yakov Kaminetzky is quoted as saying that if this work would have been completed, it would have revolutionized the way we learn.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some: Kovetz Shiurim (R. Elchanan Wasserman), Chiddushei R. Reuven (Grozovsky), Chiddushei R. Shlomo (Heiman), Shiurei R. Shmuel (Rozovsky), Shiurei R. Dovid (Povarsky), Shiurei Avi Ezri (R. Schach), Kehillos Yaakov (R. Y. Y. Kanievsky), Kuntresei Shiurim (R. Y. Z. Gustman), Reshimos Shiurim (R. Y. D. Soloveitchik), Shiurei R. Yechiel Michel (Feinstein), Shiurei R. Meshulam Dovid (Soloveitchik), Shiurei Iyun Hatalmud (R. Aba Berman), and most of the seforim by roshei yeshiva of the last century. Another good recent work on many masechtos is Birkas Avraham (R. Avraham Erlenger). There are also seforim which collect many of these chiddushim, such as Ateres Shmuel and Ohel Torah.

Comment: Excellent answer, many thanks. I will check these out.

Comment: Excellent list,however, some of those works are quite difficult reads

Comment: @sam I didn't even include Kuntres HaBiurim

Comment: double points for anybody who links these in (I assume)

Comment: @wfb Are any of these _more_ "Brisk" than the others, would you say? I'm looking for less of the pilpul, more of the chakira, if you know what I mean...

Comment: @MJG Perhaps the "reid" seforim mentioned at the end, such as Ohel Torah. There is also a sefer called "Kovetz Yesodos VeChakiros," which is available online, that consists solely of chakiros arranged by topic. The seforim Pri Moshe are also highly chakirah based, but are arranged by topic rather than by masechta.

Comment: @MJG In the above list, R. Elchanan and R. Shmuel as well as Birkas Avraham contain shorter pieces, and perhaps touch on more topics on the daf, whereas some of the others are written as "simanim" on topics, and do not relate to the line by line of the gemara. Of course, another option would be to find a shiur you enjoy and follow along that way

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest Shiurei HaRav (Soloveitcik) ,and Hararei Kedem. They both include the Brisker style analysis of chakirah. They aren't too lengthy and Hararei Kedem is very easy to follow.

Comment: Was going to be my suggestion...

Comment: Harerei Kedem is not arranged by masechet

Comment: That is why I mentioned both, and Hararei Kedem on shabbas is mostly on sugyos on Masheches shabbas ,so basically on shabbas,the Moadim also go on their topic mashechta on most topics .

Comment: I'm a big fan of Hararei Kedem. Are you referring to Shiurei HaGrid? I've actually never taken a look at that - how similar is it to Hararei Kedem?